# Execute many commands maven (mvn install:install-file) in a project free style of Hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I want to create a **project** **free style** using **Hudson** and i want to execute in it commands that installs jar in the **repository** of **Maven** by using  : **mvn install:install-file**
When i put one command it works but when i put **more that one command**:

mvn install:install-file

mvn install:install-file

Hudson executes the first command only!!

Who has a solution for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 120 jar file, it only runs the first one and exits to the command prompt.
So i've found a solution :  by using the **call** command for each call to mvn like this:

call mvn install:install-file ...
call mvn install:install-file ...

By this method you can put many commands Maven in only one project free style in Hudson.

Comment: The reason for this behavior is the last line in the `mvn.bat` - `exit /B %ERROR_CODE%`. `exit /B` ends the current batch file context. If you call a batch file from another batch file (this is what Hudson does) it will only create a new batch file context when you use the `call` command. Be careful with the the use of `exit` without the `/b` parameter. It will then end the current command shell.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you setup separate jobs in Hudson, and add a post build action on the first one to kick off the second, or a trigger on the second to kick-off after the first job completes.